# Close navigation drawer in Android by tapping on the empty portion of the screen

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer in my Android app and its visibility is controlled by the App icon in the Action Bar. However, I need to be able to close the drawer not only by tapping the app icon but also if the user taps on the empty (non-occupied) portion of the screen. This is my main layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

    android:background="@color/white"
    style="@style/ListViewSeparator"/>
```

I don't understand which layout is the one I need to set a listener to, because when I open the navigation drawer it contains my '240dp' listview, but the rest of the screen becomes like 'transparent black', I am looking for that 'transparent black' layout which is the rest of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
 mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

it was set to `LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPENED` before

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your interests. Based on the Google Examples, i implemented the same using this code:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
...
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long arg3) {
    selectItem(position);

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```